# Configure stripe recurring failure webhooks for a short period in test environment

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I am using Stripe to process payment in our product. I have the following issue,

I have a monthly plan and subscribed a customer to that plan, now I would like to test the invoice.payment_failed webhook handler whenever the payment fails on that card. However, I need to either wait minimum 1 day to test the same according to the options given in Stripe configuration.

I have checked other solutions which suggests to use a subscription with a short trial period and test the failure webook when the trial period ends, but I do not want to have a plan with a trial period. I really would like to test the failure payment hooks with the real plan with no trial in a short period (as I need to see what kind of values are passed in each attempt/call to check the number of attempts and take a decision for each attempt in the product based on that).

Is there any other way to achieve this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set a trial period on the plan itself -- you can simply set one on the individual subscription. This is the recommended way to test this, since this way you can set up a trial period of a few seconds.

In summary:

- [create a plan](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_plan) with the parameters you want
- [create a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) with a card that will be declined, e.g. [`4000 0000 0000 0341`](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards)
- [create a subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription) with [`trial_end`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription-trial_end) set to a few seconds in the future

The subscription will be successfully created (because of the trial period, there's nothing to pay right away). A few seconds later, the trial period will end and an invoice will be created (note: in test mode, it can take a few minutes after the end of the trial period for the invoice to be created). Approximately one hour after the invoice has been created, it will be closed and payment will be attempted.

Since the card you attached to the customer will always be declined, payment will fail and an [`invoice.payment_failed`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types-invoice.payment_failed) event will be generated.